# Display buttons in the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a web application in which i have these two submit button inside a table

```
   <input type="submit" value="Modifier" name="btn" style="display:inline" />
 <input type="submit" value="Exporter" name="btn" style="margin-left:10px ; display:inline" />
```

I'd like that it be displayed in the same line but i have this result:

[image: demo]

Why this happens? how can i fix my code to show the buttons in the same line?

Comment: increase the size of the table column or wrap within a div

Comment: Probably better to use `display: inline-block;` too.

Comment: Increase size of the column... if that doesn't do the trick try inline-block or float one left and one right within the column.

Comment: show us a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: What you should probably do is to reduce the widths of other columns, by removing unnecessary padding. Or possibly remove a width setting, if there is one for the column containing the buttons. The code as posted is far from sufficient: it lacks all the table markup as well as relevant CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stay away from this method of css personally, just my preference this will mean that every submit button is exactly the same but what if you don't want this styling with every submit button. But then again that method is much better than doing css inside a HTML file

```
input[type=submit]{


}
```

You're better off giving the submit buttons a class called submit then you can pick and choose which submits you want to do you're styling for

```
<input type="submit" class="submit">

.submit{
float: left;
etc. 
}
```

The main problem is your table column widths perhaps give them all a class and give them a width and/or height that meets your needs inside an external css file.

Comment: Explain how? Its been made the approved answer @JukkaK.Korpela the code which he needs is also in the CSS? Get off your high horse

Comment: Approving an answer that does not address the question is either a mistake or indicates that the intended question was not the one that was asked. The question was vague, but floating does not make elements fit into the same cell if they don’t fit as inline elements.

Comment: OR that in fact I addressed both the issue and another issue he wasn't aware of? @JukkaK.Korpela Obviously he needs to make the column width wider as well. How can you mark someone down for preaching good programming practices?

Comment: Who said it was I part answered his question and warned him about the downfalls of other methods. You clogging up pages with nothing comments and marking people down is just bitchy

Answer (score 1):

Increase your column size if not `auto` and add `float:left` to "Exporter"

Answer (score 1):

Though you could increase the width of the table column or use `display: inline-block`, maybe you want to do something else:

- Increaseing table/column width seems natural, as the two buttons look too wide to fit into that.
- Once you have it, you may prefer to use something like block display with a float component.

The inline-block performs *poorly* in Internet Explorer browsers, even in recent versions like IE9, and a lot of your visitors will be using it for a while.

```
input[type=submit] {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100px; /* or whatever fixed width you need */
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend setting up a new class so that it doesn't affect every submit button on the site. Also, setting a width of a button causes further problems if the text expands beyond it.

Comment: I'm not recommending not using a class. I'm fitting to the code the op provides :) But you're right in both advices :)

Answer (score 1):

you may try this styling;

```
input[type="submit"] {
    float: right
}
```

you may also try float left.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

Define a css rules for your submit buttons

```
input[type=submit] {
display: inline-block;
float: left; /* use this if you want them to be aligned other wise not */
width: as per needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an example.. uses bootstrap though

http://jsfiddle.net/QYBHm/

```
<h3>
<input type="button" href="/users/sign_up">Sign up</input>
or
<input type="button" href="/users/sign_in">Sign in</input>
</h3>
```

#### Sign up
    or
    Sign in

Answer (score 1):

In your table row in column with the buttons try this code

```
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<input type="submit" value="Modifier" name="btn" style="display: inline" />
 <input type="submit" value="Exporter" name="btn" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the container column isn't wide enough, so even too they are inline they appear like this. Try changing the width of that column to check if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
input[type=submit] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left; 
    width: /*adjust as per your table */;
}
```